# Oracle SQL why query is returning me multiple results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck with a query, I can't get it to work correctly.

This is what I need to do:

> Write a query that will return both the maximum and minimum average
>   salary grouped by department from the employees table.

This is what I made:

```
SELECT
(SELECT AVG(MIN(salary)) FROM employees GROUP BY department_id) As "Minimum Average salary",
(SELECT AVG(MAX(salary)) FROM employees GROUP BY department_id) As "Maximum Average Salary"
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

but it keeps returning me more than 1 row result. I can't use LIMIT 2, I'm getting an error if I query with LIMIT.

I also tried with the following query, but I'm getting error: missing expression.

```
SELECT
AVG(SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY department_id)) As "Minimum Average salary",
AVG((SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY department_id)) As "Maximum Average Salary"
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: FYI : In oracle there is no `limit`, in case you need `limit 2` you shuld write `where rownum <= 2`

Comment: Do you want to know which depratment had the lowest average salary and which department had the highest average salary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's simple why it returns as many as all records in EMPLOYEES table; because the group by is in your inner sub-query which is not applied to your main query. actually your sub-queries are executed per each row in the table and the result is returned per row.
I think this is the right query that you need:

```
SELECT AVG(min_salary) As "Minimum Average salary", AVG(max_salary) As "Maximum Average Salary"
FROM
(SELECT MIN(salary) As min_salary, MAX(salary) AS max_salary
 FROM EMPLOYEES
 GROUP BY department_id
)
```

Comment: This would return the average minimum salary.  I think the OP is looking for the minimum average salary.

Comment: I'm not sure, anyway the structure is important, MIN and AVG can be replaced no problem :)

Comment: @Zbarcea Christian thanks for accepting my answer, just please consider "David Aldridge" answer I mean that part which is about "No need for an inline view -- this works:"

Answer (score 4):

No need for an inline view -- this works:

```
select
  min(avg(salary)),
  max(avg(salary))
from
 employees
group by
  dept_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eff67/3

Comment: I guess the guy wants just one record, which is an average value. this query returns per department: as many rows as number of departments

Comment: @mostafa.S No it doesn't -- check the sqlfiddle.

Comment: @mostafa.S -- this does not return multiple records per department -- it groups by department for the avg, and then selects the min/max...

Comment: :) interesting, I didn't know that. thanks. so this one would be a better answer than mine.

Comment: @mostafa.S This is almost the exact example used in the documentation for nested aggregate functions, amusingly. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#SQLRF20035

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yeah, I checked it and I thanks for your knowledge sharing. I will utilize it from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to retrieve all the average salaries.  The outer query can then pick up the minimum and the maximum:

```
select  min(AvgSalary)
,       max(AvgSalary)
from    (
        select  avg(salary) as AvgSalary
        from    employees
        group by
                department_id
        ) SubQueryAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(salary),min(salary), avg(salary), department_id from employees  group by department_id
```